# How to align UILabel text in paragraph

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I have a small issue in setting text alignment as per client requirement. Client want text to be aligned in paragraph manner with numbers in separate line. Please see the below image the number have 19 pixels padding and text aligned in paragraph manner with 41 pixels padding.

[image]

If we set left alignment to label we will get the second line below the numeric.

[image]

I tried search for solution but not able to succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set different attributes for the question part and the answer part. You're already doing this to control the font, so it shouldn't be a big change. You need to set the paragraph style for each section. For the question section, you need to set the `firstLineHeadIndent` to 19 and the `headIndent` to 41. For the answer section, you need to set both to 41.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *questionStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
questionStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 19;
questionStyle.headIndent = 41;
NSDictionary *questionAttributes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: questionStyle,
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20]
};

NSMutableParagraphStyle *answerStyle = [questionStyle mutableCopy];
answerStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = questionStyle.headIndent;
NSDictionary *answerAttributes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: answerStyle,
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16]
};

NSMutableAttributedString *richText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[richText appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:questionText attributes:questionAttributes]];
[richText appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString:answerText attributes:answerAttributes]];

label.attributedText = richText;
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

- Use an NSAttributedString with a custom NSParagraphStyle. The first line indent can be different from the other lines (left margin).

Another possibility:

- Use a web view. What you describe is easy to configure using CSS.

Comment: Hello matt can you add sample code snippet for me with first possibility? That would be help full for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[self.titleString drawWithRect:CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, titleLabelSize.width, titleLabelSize.height)
                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine
                            attributes:@{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}
                               context:nil];
```

Comment: Hello kiran thanks for response but I am not able to full fill my requirement with above code can you please edit code and provide with some sample text snippet and screen shot that will be help full for me