# How to remove top space from UILabel paragraph?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm trying to make a description text like this, but it's not quite pretty. I want the content strings to be at the top.

The current text is rendering as follows:

[image]

I need to solve it from storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908194/how-to-align-uilabel-text-in-paragraph)

Comment: Do you really need to pin it to the bottom? You could use a `greaterThan` constraint at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `UILabel`'s bottom constraint relation `to greater than or equal` with `constant` of 0.